# Dynamics 365 - Case without a queue report

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

Is there a way to create a report in Dynamics CRM that will list all the cases that are not assigned to a queue.

I have played around with the built in reporting and can not find a way to do so. I have created a report that will look at queues that do not equal the full list of queues but shows no results.

Is there also a way to report on Dynamics CRM outside of the built in reporting tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship you are interested in is the Case > Queue Item > Queue.

If you are on V9.0 you can create an advanced find using the "Does not contain data" condition for the Queue Item from the Case entity:
[V9.0 Advanced Find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keABC.png)

Using this relationship you should be able to find cases which are not in a queue (do not have a Queue Item.

There are a few options for creating reporting with D365:

- Create Sql Server Reporting Services reports: https://community.dynamics.com/nav/b/threadpunter/archive/2017/09/26/ssrs-reports-for-dynamics-365-using-fetchxml
- PowerBI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/use-power-bi